# how to change week num to iso week in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have data that looks like this:

| CustomerID | Trans_date |
| --- | --- |
| C001 | 01-sep-22 |
| C001 | 04-sep-22 |
| C001 | 14-sep-22 |
| C002 | 03-sep-22 |
| C002 | 01-sep-22 |
| C002 | 18-sep-22 |
| C002 | 20-sep-22 |
| C003 | 02-sep-22 |
| C003 | 28-sep-22 |
| C004 | 08-sep-22 |
| C004 | 18-sep-22 |

after processing using this query:

```
WITH CTE (customerID,FirstWeek,RN) AS (
        SELECT customerID,MIN(DATEPART(week,tp_date)) TransWeek,
        ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by customerID ORDER BY DATEPART(week,tp_date) asc ) FROM all_table
        GROUP BY customerID,DATEPART(week,tp_date)
    ) 
    
    SELECT CTE.customerID, CTE.FirstWeek,  
         (select TOP 1 (DATEPART(week,c.tp_date))   
            from all_table c 
                where c.customerID = CTE.customerID AND DATEPART(week,C.tp_date) > CTE.FirstWeek 
                    )   SecondWeek 
    FROM CTE  
    WHERE RN = 1
```

the result is like this

| CustomerID | firstweek | secondweek |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C001 | 36 | 37 |
| C002 | 36 | 39 |
| C003 | 36 | 40 |
| C004 | 37 | 39 |

but the results will be appropriate when using the weeknum in excel. but what i hope  the result is isoweek format which will look like this

| CustomerID | firstweek | secondweek |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C001 | 35 | 37 |
| C002 | 35 | 37 |
| C003 | 35 | 39 |
| C003 | 36 | 37 |

Comment: Can you explain what your query should accomplish in your own words?

Comment: Well [`DATEPART` supports `ISO_WEEK` in addition to `WEEK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql).

Comment: @RhythmWasaLurker so just change week to iso_week?

Answer (score 0):

Have create a small fiddle to help: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/a7Yr0Nx7)

And as I understand I would just use min and max values of weeks grouped by customer

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/a7Yr0Nx7 - fiddle link

Answer (score 0):

Datepart has an isowk parameter.
So instead of

```
DATEPART(week,...
```

use

```
DATEPART(isowk,...
```